# How to deserialize in MySQL the Polygon data for fetching latitude/longitude?

Tags: mysql, deserialization, polygon, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have saved into one field of the table the geospatial data. Its type is `Polygon`.

If to use such query:

```
SELECT AsWKT(area) as `polygon` FROM geo.info_buildings;
```

I get the next type of result, for e.g.:

```
POLYGON((55.4295824 36.8635427),(55.4296539 36.8636714),
(55.4291776 36.8644788),(55.4290999 36.86435)
```

I want to know, how can I parse/deserialize the `Polygon` object from SQL commands in such way that I shall be able to get `longitude/latitude` from each point of the `Polygon`.

As I understand, the way to deserialize is:

**Attention**

I didn't have good skills in SQL, so the next pseudo-code is just only a concept/idea, so be patient and kind please :) and forgive me my lack of knowledge in the field of MySQL.

1). Make smth similar to the `foreach()` block.

Pseudo-code:

```
foreach (Point p in Polygon) { ... }
```

2). Then in this `foreach` block do smth. like:

```
foreach (Point p in Polygon)
{
    SET @var1 = p.GetLatitude();
    SET @var2 = p.GetLongitude();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to extract the points of a polygon or a line you must use the "[NumPoints (ls)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_numpoints)" to determine the number of points, then you must use the command [PointN (ls, N)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_pointn) to scroll through them one by one and extract the coordinates, in the following link you can find an example of each

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/geometry-property-functions.html